# Artifactory local Composer repository won't download a package

Tags: composer-php, artifactory

I have a local composer repository in Artifactory named `php-test`.

I have used the user interface to deploy a zip file representing a package.

When I then attempt to do a `composer install` I get the following error:

```
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing com.foo/bar (0.0.6-alpha): Downloading (failed)

  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "https://foo.jfrog.io/foo/api/composer/php-test/direct-dists/foo/bar/bar-0.0.6-alpha.
  zip" file could not be downloaded (HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found)
```

The issue, I think, is the fact that it is somehow adding `direct-dists/` to the path. I don't understand where this is coming from or how to change it. I *think* that the `direct-dists` bit is put there by Artifactory when it indexes the repository.

For example, there is a file in the repository named `.composer/p/com.foo/bar.json`. Inside that file is this bit here:

```
{
    "packages": {
        "com.foo/bar": {
            "0.0.6-alpha": {
                "name": "com.foo/bar",
                "version": "0.0.6-alpha",
                "dist": {
                    "type": "zip",
                    "url": "direct-dists/foo/bar/bar-0.0.6-alpha.zip"
                },
```

So obviously this is why composer thinks it wants to download it with the `direct-dists/` prefix...but shouldn't Artifactory be stripping that off?

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but hope will help to others.

I was getting same issue on Magento 2 while running command:

```
composer install
```

I applied every solution but no success. After debugging, found "Magento authentication keys" is missing. Then I add "auth.json" in the magento root folder with the following content and issue resolved.

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "07b4696745540607b5eb9e6a6ea44444",
            "password": "c3fe8c2b80d5ba56777952a5ad744444"
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,